# Shifted array subtraction in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
B = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I need to subtract A from B but not in the normal way. I need to subtract 
0th element of A from 4th element of B, 1st element of A from 5th element of B i.e. `B[4] - A[0] , B[5] - A[1] , ... , B[n] - A[n-4]` and so on. In short I need to shift elements of A by 4 indices and subtract from B and wrap the difference around. Is there a easy way to do this in python?

Comment: Yes there is. Have you made any attempt to find it? This is not a free coding service after all.

Comment: Yes, what I am doing at present is cut off the last 4 elements of array A and add those to its front. The new array is then subtracted from B in the normal way.

Comment: Also, your problem spec is incomplete. Do you want the difference to be 8 elements shorter than either A or B, or do you want to wrap the difference around?

Comment: Please show the code of how you do it now. Edit it into the question.

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=numpy%20shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
numpy.roll(B, -4) - A
```

If you don't need to wrap around, you can use something like:

```
>>> B[4:] - A[:-4]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Did you mean -4?

Comment: Right now you are subtracting A[0] from B[-4] if I understand correctly

Answer (score 0):

if you convert the array into a pandas Series you can use the [shift() method.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)